# What's difference between "Above me" and "Over me"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

He is above me. (Sense- Senior to)

He is over me.(Sense-Senior to)

Are there any difference in meaning?

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: He is above me vs He is over me.(In terms of seniority )

Comment: I understand that. I mean, who is saying this? Who are they talking about? Who are they talking to? Is it in the military? An office? Is it spoken or written? Is it a text message or an application form? Please use the "Edit" button to add all this information into the question

Comment: In office.......

Comment: I would understand _above_ to have more of a sense of 'at a higher level in the hierarchy' and _over_ to imply 'with responsibility for supervising my work' - but that's not a hard-and-fast distinction.

Comment: @KateBunting Again, answer-worthy. Pretty much exactly what I was going to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the most general context of a workplace hierarchy, someone who is *over* you is *immediately* above you, ie they *oversee* your work. Some organisations call this your 'line manager', or your 'immediate manager'. But your manager may have someone else senior to them, and so on and so on... all of those people are 'above' you, but not necessarily 'over' you if they have nothing to do with overseeing your day-to-day work.

Of course, workplaces often come with their own terminology and workplace jargon. There are no rules about these, and many questions here are about the unusual use of English words in the workplace because as jargon they do not always follow their dictionary definition or grammatical usage. If your workplace uses terms differently, that doesn't mean anyone is wrong or right.

Answer (score 3):

There is no absolute distinction between the two, but in the business context I (and @gotube!) would say that *He is above me* generally means 'He is at a higher level in the organisation than I am' and *He is over me* means 'he has responsibility for supervising my work.'